# Using recursive function when traversing through a dictionary in order to populate an empty list of dicts

Tags: python, json

I have a list of dictionaries, which is derived from a `JSON` file. Here is a `JSON` file (it was purposefully simplified):

```
[
   {
      "one":{
         "private":{
            "resource":"qwerty"
         },
         "children":[
            "test"
         ],
         "public":{
            "-name":"gf"
         },
         "parents":[
            "twenty"
         ],
         "id":"one",
         "properties":{
            "COLOR":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "H":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "TO_NOTIFY":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "environment":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "EMAIL_TO":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "W":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "Y":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "X":{
               "-type":"double"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "two":{
         "private":{
            "resource":"qwerty"
         },
         "children":[
            "test"
         ],
         "public":{
            "-name":"gf"
         },
         "parents":[
            "one"
         ],
         "id":"two",
         "properties":{
            "COLOR":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "H":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "TO_NOTIFY":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "environment":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "EMAIL_TO":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "W":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "Y":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "X":{
               "-type":"double"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "three":{
         "private":{
            "resource":"qwerty"
         },
         "children":[
            "test"
         ],
         "public":{
            "-name":"gf"
         },
         "parents":[
            "two"
         ],
         "id":"three",
         "properties":{
            "COLOR":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "H":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "TO_NOTIFY":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "environment":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "EMAIL_TO":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "W":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "Y":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "X":{
               "-type":"double"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "four":{
         "private":{
            "resource":"qwerty"
         },
         "children":[
            "test"
         ],
         "public":{
            "-name":"gf"
         },
         "parents":[
            "one"
         ],
         "id":"four",
         "properties":{
            "COLOR":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "H":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "TO_NOTIFY":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "environment":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "EMAIL_TO":{
               "-type":"string"
            },
            "W":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "Y":{
               "-type":"double"
            },
            "X":{
               "-type":"double"
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

***My goal:*** Update current `JSON` (what you see in the file) so it includes only `requested` entries. `Requested` here means that a user gives me a number of a needed entry, let's say `three`. I want to append that `three` to a new list. Also, I need to find a parent `parents` of `three`, and append it to that list as well. I also need to find a parent of the subsequent entry and so on.

How do I do that? Do I use recursion for this? Here is what I have so far:

```
import json

with open('/home/intern/nbf/1.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Finds a parent of a node (and of subsequent nodes if any)
def find_parent(node, data = data):

    l = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for k in data[i]:
            if k == node:
                l.append(data[i])

find_parent('three')
```

I still lack the part, which would check for `parents` and add them to the list `l`.

Comment: If you're not set on using python, you could look at [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this.

Comment: I was looking at jq, but for some reason decided to go with Python... Do you think jq is a better fit here?

Comment: Honestly I only recently learned of jq's existence, it just seemed like it was made for this sort of thing. If you've looked at it and decided python would be better for this, you're more qualified than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have finished the process for "three", you then call the function again (using the same list) but with both of the parents of "three". You have to be careful though if you have cycles, because then this would never terminate.

```
def find_parent(node, data, l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for k in data[i]:
            print(k)

            if k == node:
                l.append(data[i])
                for parent in data[i][k]["parents"]:
                    find_parent(parent, data, l)
    return l
```

Comment: I just checked it out and it seems to work very well. I will test more tomorrow and provide an update. Thanks a lot!